# При компиляции сбитая кодировка

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Сегодня поменяли ПК на более мощный. Установили такую же версию Visual Studio (2015 Enterprise). Но при компиляции все русские символы не отображаются некорректно. Причем этот баг только при компиляции исключительно данной программы.

Что выдается в консоли:

> Aua?ai ?a?ei ?aaiou

Что должно быть:

> Выбран режим работы

Программа запускается как консольное приложение, которое запускает окно (WinForms). Если создать новый проект, то в консоли пишет все хорошо (вывод идет просто через *Console.log* как в новом проекте, так и в проблемном).

Думал что может кодировка отличается у меня, но на другом ПК так же отображается. Код не менялся.

В чем может быть проблема? Пытался [декодером](https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/) определить что за сбитая кодировка, но безрезультатно. Компилятор не выдает никаких ошибок что нет ссылки на то-либо, а так же что что-то не может найти.

Кодировка системы cp-1251.

.Net Framework 3.5

Есть скрин как это все.. Не только в консоли такая проблема:

[image: sdc]

Comment: А кодировка консоли? Я думаю `1252` или `866`, как по умолчанию. Откройте консоль и введите `chcp`, и покажите что отдаст.

Comment: @ヒミコ вызовом *Encoding.Default* выводится cp-1251. Если бы во всех программах такое стало, то да. Но я смотрел, только в этой.. Как будет возможность напишу. ПК рабочий ))

Comment: Да поймите, не важно что отдает `Encoding.Default`, покажите что отдаст консоль.

Comment: @ヒミコ завтра смогу только посмотреть. Напишу сразу же. Спасибо за мысль!

Comment: @ヒミコ `866` выдает. Выше прикрепил скрин как выглядит сама проблема...

Comment: а в какой кодировке у вас сам файл Program.cs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Все дело в кодировке файла исходного кода. По какой-то причине изменилась кодировка.. с UTF-8 поменялся на ANSI

Решением является изменение кодировки исходного файла.

Спасибо @Konst за наводку.

Comment: контроль версий? кто-то установил настройку кодировки для исходников (или этого конкретного файла?). Все системы контроля версий это позволяют, лючше всего явно задавать UTF-8.с UTF-8 поменялся на ANSI - это изменение необратимое, можно только откатывать или перенабивать текст.

Comment: @Swift почему не обратимо? Попробуйте, например, через notepad++ перекодировать файл и обратно. А про из-за чего сменилась буду разбираться. Возможно именно то, что вы сказали и произошло. Это не приоритет в данный момент, поэтому после окончания работы и буду смотреть

Comment: @pavl_o потому что в UTF-8 больше символов, чем в однобайтовых. Возьмите любую греческую букву и попробуйте её "перекодировать" туда и обратно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен. Но если такие символы не используются, то все хорошо будет же. Тут просто уже нюанс какие символы используются.